# Extract a part of one line and sort

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have output similar to the following:

```
[test output] my name is bob this is a random string
[test output] my name is jim this is a randong string2
[test output] my name is bob this is a randong string3
[test output] my name is alice this is a randong string4
[test output] my name is bob this is a randong string5
[test output] my name is dave this is a randong string6
[test output] my name is jim this is a randong string7
[test output] my name is jim this is a randong string8
```

Expected output:

```
my name is bob
my name is jim
my name is alice
my name is dave
```

After the name could be any string, I am trying to output only the above, one line for each name. It doesn't matter what order they come in.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ s = $3" "$4" "$5" "$6 };!(s in a){a[s];print s}' <file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind sorted output then it can be also done with `cut` and `sort`:

```
cut -d' ' -f3-6 file | sort -u
```

- `-d` at `cut` specifies delimiter which is a space in your case.
- `-f` at `cut` specifies which fields you want to output. In your case you want all fields from 3 to 6.
- `-u` at `sort` outputs only first of equal lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` also

```
sed -e 's/^.*] //g' -e 's/ this.*$'//g file | sort -u
```